# durandal knockout - strange binding / timing error?

Tags: durandal

I am experiencing some strange binding / timing behavior - i have pasted the relevant code. When i step through the code slowly manually in chrome it populates my drop down correctly when i let it run normally it does not.... what am i doing wrong? I have put in the console output where the timing of my 'got provinces' is different.

```
 var provinces = ko.observableArray();

 var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        viewAttached:viewAttached,
        title: 'Home View',
        provinces: provinces,
    };

return vm;

  function activate() {
            getProvinces(provinces);
            return true;
    }

function viewAttached() {
    console.log("got data");
}
```

The simple ajax call is as follows where i pass in my observable (this is taken almost exactly from the John Papa pluralsight demo):

```
getProvinces: function (observableArray) {
   observableArray([]);

   var options = {
        url: currentServer + 'regions/GetInUseProvinces',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
    };

    $.ajax(options).then(querySucceded);

    function querySucceded(data) {
        var provinces = [];
        data.forEach(function(item) {
            var s = new MedappData.Data.Province(item.Name, item.ID);
            provinces.push(s);
        });
        observableArray(provinces);
        console.log('got provinces');
    }
},
```

The console output differs as follows between the two.

When i put break points in and step through it manually i get the following and it works perfectly:

```
["Activating", Object]
["[viewmodels/shell] ", "Medapp loaded..."] system.js:62
["Activating Route", Object, Object, n.Object]
["Activating", Object]
["Binding", "views/shell", Object]
got provinces vendor:5319
["Binding", "views/nav", ko.bindingContext]
["Binding", "views/home", Object]
["Binding", "views/footer", ko.bindingContext]
got data
```

When i remove my break points and let it runs the output is as follow and nothing is populated.

```
["Activating", Object]
["[viewmodels/shell] ", "Medapp loaded..."] system.js:62
["Activating Route", Object, Object, n.Object]
["Activating", Object]
["Binding", "views/shell", Object]
["Binding", "views/nav", ko.bindingContext]
["Binding", "views/home", Object]
["Binding", "views/footer", ko.bindingContext]
got provinces vendor:5319
got data
```

Comment: The solution to this... is to remove my populate method from the activate() event and put it into the viewAttached() event. This seems to solve the problem... however i am not sure i understand... Everywhere i seem to read that activate() is the place to load data???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getProvinces` is a async operation, so you have to return a promise in order to allow Durandal to figure out when it's allowed to continue composing. Returning `true` after an async operation doesn't do that.

`$.ajax(...` already returns a promise, so changing `getProvinces` to

```
return $.ajax(options).then(querySucceded);
```

and in `activate`

```
function activate() {
    return getProvinces(provinces);
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: as always your snippet fixed my nightmare.

Comment: Yes. When you made the async call you did not tell Durandal to wait for it before continuing onward. You do that by returning the promise from the async call, as shown here. It worked in the debugger because when you stepped through it, it had enough time to complete as you were stepping :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing as well. However, this does bring up one question.

If you have multiple async tasks pending (for example fetching multiple different data types), does it make sense to then && the promises for the return value of activate?

Comment: `return $.when(...)` is probably what you're looking for. BTW: Don't hijack questions, ask new ones ;-).