# Durandal KO binding when data is fetched in activate

Tags: durandal, knockout-mapping-plugin

A parameter governs what data is to be displayed. The parameter is retrieved from activationData in the activate method of the view model and used in a call to a Web Api method. Data is returned, and added to the view model like this

```
define(['durandal/app', 'knockout', 'moment'], 
       function (app, config, ko, moment) {

  var vm = {
    app: app
  };

  vm.activate = function (activationData) {
    vm.ChecklistInstanceId = activationData.ChecklistInstanceId;
    $.ajax({
      url: "api/ChecklistInstance/" + vm.ChecklistInstanceId,
      headers: { Authorization: "Session " + app.SessionToken() }
    }).done(function (data) {
      $.extend(vm, ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
    });    
  };

  return vm;

});
```

Inspecting the viewmodel immediately after it is extended reveals that it is decorated with observables exactly as expected. For example, vm.Caption() exists and returns the string I expect, and vm.Section() is an appropriately populated observable array, and so on down a fairly elaborate object graph.

The problem is *the binding phase has already occurred*, and at that time the view model lacks all the observables to which I'm trying to bind.

Two possible strategies suggest themselves:

- obtain the parameter earlier
- re-bind

I don't know how to do either of those things. Can anyone tell me how to re-organise my code to allow binding to parametrically fetched data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third possibility occurred to me:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'knockout', 'moment'], 
       function (app, config, ko, moment) {

  var vm = {
    app: app,
    Caption: ko.observable(),
    Section: ko.observableArray()
  };

  vm.activate = function (activationData) {
    vm.ChecklistInstanceId = activationData.ChecklistInstanceId;
    $.ajax({
      url: "api/ChecklistInstance/" + vm.ChecklistInstanceId,
      headers: { Authorization: "Session " + app.SessionToken() }
    }).done(function (data) {
      var foo = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
      vm.Caption(foo.Caption());
      vm.Section(foo.Section());
    });    
  };

  return vm;

});
```

This works because all the observables exist in the binding phase. This might seem surprising given that I describe only the root of a potentially deep object graph, but the fact that the observable array is empty causes the binding phase to exit without a hitch.

Later in the activate handler, values are added to the observable array *after* ko.mapping has its way with the data, and binding succeeds.

I have a sense of dèja vu from this: it is eerily reminiscent of problems solved using forward declarations in TurboPascal back in the eighties. La plus ça change...

Answer (score 0):

In order to work on a fully-constructed view, you will need to move your logic to either the `attached` handler or the `compositionComplete` handler.  As you said, at the *activate* stage, the DOM isn't yet fully constructed.  You can read about these lifecycle callbacks [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html).

Typically, what we do is pass the activationData in through the `activate` handler, store the activationData locally (if your viewModel is instance-based, then on a property in the constructor), and then reference that activationData in the `attached` or the `compositionComplete` handler.

You can fetch the data in the `activate` handler, and then store the data locally.  But that's all you should do there.  Reserve view-related logic for later in the cycle.  In this case, you may need to return a promise from `activate`, and then resolve upon receiving your data.  You can read about it [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Activators.html).

**UPDATE**

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17985725/3174746), and the conversation there.

Comment: I followed your link. Do I understand correctly that the essence of what you are trying to tell me is that it's a bad idea to make activate take a while to return? I would have thought that the done method of the ajax call in the solution I proposed is *already* set up to populate the data asynchronously. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: Never mind, I see now that if I capture the parameter in activate and then use it to fetch data in attached I can simplify back to `$.extend(vm, ko.mapping.fromJS(data));` I'm not sure how to rewrite my ajax call so it give me a promise object to return but I'm sure I can work that out.

Comment: @PeterWone No, I'm not saying it's a bad idea.  In fact, there will have to be a bit of a delay since you're fetching data asynchronously.  Again, returning may not be necessary.  I don't, and I fetch data async in `activate` handlers as well.